# Running tensorboard behind traefik

Tags: tensorboard, traefik

I am trying to add a tensorboard container to an existing microservice structure running behind traefik. Unfortunately, the traefik version is 1.5 so a lot of recent articles are not helpful.

Since there is a default service on `www.my-server.com/`, I am trying to have traefik redirect to the tensorboard service from `www.my-server.com/tensorboard/`. Here is my docker-compose (the part relevant for tensorboard)

```
  tensorboard:

    build: "./docker/build/images/tensorflow"
    container_name: tensorboard
    command: tensorboard --logdir=runs --port=8888 --host=0.0.0.0
    labels:
      - log.level=debug
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.my-server.com;PathPrefix:/tensorboard/
    volumes:
      - ./machine_learning:/opt/src
    ipc: host
```

When I visit `www.my-server.com/tensorboard/` I get "Not Found". If I remove the host argument from the command I get "Bad Gateway". I don't understand what either of these mean but I think one of them is being able to reach the service but the service is getting the request with the prefix tensorboard and is complaining.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the following command will solve this problem

`tensorboard --logdir mylogdir --bind_all --path_prefix=/tensorboard`